# tomcat + Jenkins + Java EE source = failed compile

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, jboss, jenkins

I'm having a tough time getting my very simply Java EE source to compile in Jenkins that's running on tomcat6 (on Centos 6.x). I've tried downloading JBoss but can't find the Java EE jar files so I can include those in my ANT script. I downloaded JavaEE from Oracle which is the .sh shell script (80mb) that I guess "installs" java ee by extracting or compiling the various jars. Problem is it won't run since the Oracle shell script requires an X11 instance to be running (GUI)... but this is a headless server.

The goal is to have a working nightly build of a project that uses JavaEE.

I need to either somehow find how to use JBoss for only it's java ee libraries (so i can compile my code) or need to somehow get oracle's offering to work? or are there other options for my setup?

Here's my Jenkins/Ant log output:

```
build-project:
 [echo] JUtils: /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/build.xml
[javac] Compiling 27 source files to /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/target/tmp
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:21: error: package javax.mail does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.Message;
[javac]                  ^
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:22: error: package javax.mail does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.MessagingException;
[javac]                  ^
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:23: error: package javax.mail does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.Session;
[javac]                  ^
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:24: error: package javax.mail does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.Transport;
[javac]                  ^
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:25: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
[javac]                           ^
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:26: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
[javac]                           ^
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:27: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
[javac] import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
[javac]                           ^
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             throws AddressException, MessagingException {
[javac]                    ^
[javac]   symbol:   class AddressException
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             throws AddressException, MessagingException {
[javac]                                      ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MessagingException
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Session
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
[javac]                           ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable Session
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MimeMessage
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
[javac]                                   ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MimeMessage
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
[javac]                             ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];
[javac]                                           ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
[javac]                                ^
[javac]   symbol:   class InternetAddress
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:76: error: package Message does not exist
[javac]             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
[javac]                                         ^
[javac] /usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/src/net/snakedoc/jutils/SendEmail.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Transport
[javac]   location: class SendEmail
[javac] 19 errors

BUILD FAILED
/usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/JUtils-Nightly/workspace/build.xml:54: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 4 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

EDIT: (Ant build script)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="JUtils">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../../../Program Files/eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64/eclipse"/>
<property name="JAVAEE_HOME" value="/opt/jboss/modules/**"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.7"/>
<property name="source" value="1.7"/>
<property name="dest_dir" value="target"/>
<property name="tmp_dir" value="tmp"/>
<property name="jar_name" value="JUtils"/>
<path id="javaee.libraryclasspath">
        <pathelement location="${JAVAEE_HOME}"/>
    </path>
<tstamp>
    <format property="build.datestamp" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" locale="en,US"/>
</tstamp>
<path id="JUtils.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/h2-1.3.170.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/hsqldb.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jt400.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/mariadb-java-client-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"/>
    <path refid="javaee.libraryclasspath"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${dest_dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}/src"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}/doc"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}/lib"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}/META-INF"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${dest_dir}">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="**/*"/>
            <exclude name="target/**"/>
            <exclude name="logs/**"/>
            <exclude name="bin/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${dest_dir}"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project,jar" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="JUtils.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target name="create_manifest">
    <manifest file="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0"/>
        <attribute name="Website" value="www.snakedoc.net"/>
        <attribute name="Project" value="JUtils-${build.datestamp}"/>
    </manifest>
</target>
<target depends="create_manifest" name="jar">
    <jar destfile="${dest_dir}/${jar_name}-${build.datestamp}.jar" basedir="${dest_dir}/${tmp_dir}"/>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
<target name="DBTest">
    <java classname="net.snakedoc.jutils.testsuite.DBTest" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="JUtils.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: *I downloaded JavaEE from Oracle* for your information, this is commonly known as GlassFish. Have you tried with [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)?

Comment: Tomcat is a Web Server not an Application Server it is not EE compliant. [Look here](http://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/09/26/113/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your current errors are related to Java Mail.

- You can download the JavaMail API library from the [Oracle JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html) page.
- You can download the JEE6 SDK from [Oracle Java EE 6 SDK Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) page

On a side note, using Maven would trivialize some of these dependency issues.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: While you're right with the Java Mail libraries, I don't understand how OP couldn't get them from JBoss nor GlassFish jars =\.

Comment: That would be a weird way to get the compilation dependencies, for which you only need the API libraries. JBoss/Glassfish/Weblogic etc, all supply the implementation libraries. And not all of them contain easily extracted JARs - JBoss 7, for example, uses OSGI modules.

Comment: I actually setup a working JBoss server, ran it from the ./standalone.sh file. I had the same exact compilation errors... I had figured JBoss would have everything my project needed to compile.. but perhaps I did something wrong. See my EDIT above for my Ant build script...

Comment: @Preception that's what was weird to me, I was browsing the extracted JBoss 7 directories and only ran across OSGI directories and some directories called javax... but could not find the jars I needed or can't seem to figure out how to get all those loaded to my classpath for compilation.

Comment: @SnakeDoc - yes, JBoss 7 uses an implicit module to declare the Java EE API dependencies. You can see the module.xml file under modules/javaee/api/main in your JBoss distribution folder. But there are no JAR's included with it. I'll add the Maven dependencies for Java EE to my answer, and where to download the JEE API when trying to setup an Ant build.